# Central curve $\alpha^*(t)$ is uniquely determined by the following condition?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

Let $\alpha:I\longrightarrow \mathbb R^2$ be a regular curve with curvature $\kappa>0$ and normal vector $N$. I need some help to show the following:

Show the curve, $$\alpha^*(t)=\alpha(t)+\frac{1}{\kappa}N,$$ is uniquely determined by the condition that its tangent line in each point $\alpha^*(t)$ is the normal line of $\alpha$ in $\alpha(t)$.

I didn't even understand what I'm supposed to show, can anyone explain it?

Any help will be valuable.

Answer (score 0):

There's a hypothesis missing here. The original curve $\alpha$ is arclength parametrized. Then differentiate $\alpha^*$ (which is *not* arclength parametrized). What do you find?

By the way, if you want another resource for this sort of stuff — and more exercises — you might check out my free text at [Shifrin Diff Geo notes](http://math.uga.edu/~shifrin/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, I'll check your notes, it sounds very good =D

Comment: I'll have to give two lectures about conjugate points, can you recommend me some material asbout it?

Comment: That's one level up from my notes. What sources have you looked at?

Comment: Up to now I looked at manfredo's differential geometry of curves and surfaces..

Comment: Geometric topology more than anything, I'm really at the intro stage (but I know Metric spaces well). Also was I seriously given a temp-ban for "Before toilet paper life was great, then we wondered why we called that great! Enjoy your unsliced bread :P "