# How to show $\displaystyle \kappa=\frac{\langle \alpha^{''}, J(\alpha^{'})\rangle}{\langle \alpha^{'}, \alpha^{'}\rangle^{3/2}}$?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves

Let $\alpha(t)=(x(t), y(t))$ be a regular curve (not necessarily an unit speed curve) in $\mathbb R^2$. How to show the curvature of $\alpha$ is given by $$\displaystyle \kappa=\frac{\langle \alpha^{''}, J(\alpha^{'})\rangle}{\langle \alpha^{'}, \alpha^{'}\rangle^{3/2}},$$ where $J$ is the operator given by $J(a, b)=(-b, a)$? Any help will be valuable.

Comment: Note that the numerator is the 2-dimensional 'cross product' of $\alpha''$ and $\alpha'$, a measure of the orthogonality between the two.  What's your definition of the curvature that you're trying to show equal, the radius of the osculating circle or something else?  (The expression you've written often *is* taken as the definition...)

Comment: That is a problem because my textbook defines $\kappa$ only for unit speed curves in $\mathbb R^2$ as $\kappa=\langle T^{'}, N\rangle$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition, curvature $\kappa$ is given by the equation $T' = \kappa N$ for an arclength parametrization (where $T$, $N$ are, respectively, the unit tangent and unit normal). Note that $N=J(T)$.

In general, $\alpha' = \upsilon T$, where $\upsilon = \|\alpha'\|$ is the speed of the curve. Differentiating, $\alpha'' = \upsilon' T + \kappa\upsilon^2 N$, and so
$$\kappa = \frac{\alpha''\cdot N}{\upsilon^2} = \frac{\alpha''\cdot J(T)}{\|\alpha'\|^2}.$$
Your formula is actually wrong. Since $\alpha'$ has length $\upsilon$, the correct formula should be
$$\kappa = \frac{\alpha''\cdot J(\alpha')}{\|\alpha'\|^3}.$$

**EDIT**: OK, the formula is no longer wrong ... lest we confuse readers in the future.

Comment: Good catch on the slip - note that one easy way of seeing this is to try a scaling reparameterization $t=\mu t$ and then use the chain rule to see what effect it has on the formula; $\kappa$ should remain unchanged under such a reparameterization.

Comment: Because $J$ is linear and $T=\alpha'/\upsilon$ :)

Comment: All right, I deleted the comment because I had seen it =)

Comment: You troublemaker!

Comment: @TedShifrin can you check this another question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/778725/central-curve-alphat-is-uniquely-determined-by-the-following-condition it is related to this one..

Comment: I put a generous hint for you :)